# Unix shell script file to replace itself

Tags: shell, unix, copy

I have a `shell script` (***myfile.ksh***) file which will have sequence of command.
Somewhere there will be a command to replace this *myfile.ksh* with new file.

I studied that inside my *myfile.ksh*, I can start a new process with `&`.

`. newfiletocopy.ksh &`

I have put lot of effort to copy & replace the own file.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: It is really hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish. Consider editing your question to show a 'use-case' for how and why you need a "unix shell script file to replace itself". Show 1. what you type on the command line, what happens in step 2, step 3, .... etc. The '&' only says, run the current command in the background  and go to the next line in the script, execute that cmd without waiting for the backgrounded command. There is also `exec`, but it is for advanced usage. If you can't describe in simple language what  use-case requirement is, you probably don't need exec. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It is a little unclear what you want, but if you want to copy another file over the one currently being executed, adding something simple like this should work:

```
cp newfiletocopy.ksh $0
```